# Read only debugfs file is being written to. Why is that?

Tags: linux, file, permissions, filesystems

I have created a file using `debugfs` API inside `/sys/kernel/debug/test/testFile`. I have created the file with mode set to `444`, so it is now read only.

Now I have essentially followed this [tutorial](http://blog.techveda.org/debugfs/) in creating this `debugfs` file. And for this file both `read` and `write` are define. Moreover, concretely, I create file using this:

`debugfs_create_file("testFile", 444, pDebugfs,
        NULL,  &debugfs_fops)`

File is successfully created and I can easily read from it by `cat ...` but why I can write to it too even though I can explicitly created as `read only`. I am logged in as root. Why is that? Should not it not allow me to write to it?

Finally, `ls -l` results:

`-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 جون   28 15:27 /sys/kernel/debug/test/testFile`

Now, you may argue that since I am *root*, I can write to any file. Well, then if you search `let's access blob file` on the page, the OP cannot write to blob file, even though as root, because it is read only. Why is that?

Comment: This is a normal behavior, root has rw access on all files at all times. If you want to protect a file even from root you can do `chattr +i testFile` this will add `Immutable` attribute, then it can not be modified.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr

Comment: @DavidDomain but why can't the original author not edit the blob file even through root? He does not seem to add the Immutable attribute.